# Initiating a CORS request from a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, cors

So I have been trying to implement a CORS using JavaScript for a client. I ran into an odd problem I simply don't understand.  Please forgive me by keeping the name of the server I am hitting private.

So if I run the code as a script into a browser and watch the console (tested on firefox and chrome) it works.  But once I incorporate the code into a user driven button it does not send out the request.  In firefox I can see that the connection is not secure so it does not send it.

So here is the example using just javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript">
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', 'https://api.somewhere.com');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic 123456ABCDE');
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://api.somewhere.com');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
  }
};

var body = {
  'testBody': "somedata"
};

request.send(JSON.stringify(body));

</script>
```

**Then here is the example using the a javascript button**

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
<!--

var authcode = 'Basic 1ab1b2b2b4km='

function response () 
{
  if (this.readyState === 4) 
  {
    console.log('readyState:', this.readyState);  
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Response:', this.responseText);
  }
};

function errorError()
{
    console.log('Error Status:', this.status);
}

function GetData()
{

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', 'https://api.somewhere.com');

  request.onreadystatechange = response;
  request.onerror = errorError;


  var body = {
    'testdata': "data"
  };

  console.log('Request Body:', body);

  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authcode );
  request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://api.somewhere.com'); 
  request.send(JSON.stringify(body));  

};



-->
</SCRIPT>


      <div class="w3-row-padding w3-half">
        <p>Weight (LBS)</p>
        <div class="w3-quarter">
           <input type="text" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="1">
        </div>
         <div class="w3-third">
           <input type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-red" value="Get Quote" onClick="GetDAta();">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:html5] but your HTML (`<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">`) is HTML 3.2.

Comment: So the suggested way for html5 is just <script> code goes here <script> ?

Comment: Can you supply a full set of request and response headers, for both the POST request **and** for the preceding preflight OPTIONS request (if there is one).

Answer (score 1):

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is not a request header, but a response header.
There is nothing you can do if the origin doesn't change or remove this header.

Maybe the rest of your code is fine, check the log of the Chrome browser for example, it will show 'caution marks' if there is an authoritive problem.

Answer (score 0):

> In firefox I can see that the connection is not secure so it does not send it.

If it is refusing to send the request because you are mixing HTTP and HTTPS then you can't fix that with CORS. You need to match your security levels.

---

Asides:

> Initiating a CORS request from a HTML page

CORS, on the client, is handled almost entirely transparently by the browser. You don't do anything special to send a CORS request.

> ```
> request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://api.somewhere.com');
> ```

This is a **response** header, not a request header, it has no place on the request.

Comment: I appreciate your response.   One comment I should have added, both examples are loaded locally as a file.  In the first example that does work there is really no HTML but just logs to console.  The second example is tied to a button that imitates the request locally